# Displaying Gallery Page with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This my displayed gallery:
[image]

And this is what I want
[image]

I want to displayed image like that, a little messy but awesome

And this my trouble when some image have different height
[image]

there have whitespace and does not automatically fill the whitespace section So this whitespace should be fill.

This my HTML & CSS Code :

```css
.detail-img{
   width: 23%;
   margin: 10px;
   position: relative;
   min-height: 280px;
   max-height: 450px;
}
.galeri-row{
    margin: auto;
}

.galeri-row img{
    border-radius: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row galeri-row justify-content-md-center">
      <a href="#" class="detail-img">
        <img src="img/src">
        <div class="detail-text">
          <span class="my-tag btn-success">TAG</span>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur...
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="detail-img galeri-sm">
        <img src="img/src">
        <div class="detail-text">
          <span class="my-tag btn-success">TAG</span>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="detail-img galeri-sm">
        <img src="img/src">
        <div class="detail-text">
          <span class="my-tag btn-success">TAG</span>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="detail-img">
        <img src="img/src">
        <div class="detail-text">
          <span class="my-tag btn-success">TAG</span>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
           ...................
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is commonly known as a "masonry" layout. Bootstrap 4 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468140/bootstrap-4-masonry-layout-utilizing-flexbox-grid

Comment: Thank, for information, now I can continue my task

Answer (score -1):

if you want to stick to fixed column layout I would use flexbox, with a flex-direction: column, to manage each column individually