# Bootstrap collapse element row height issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to prevent the following issue from happening when using bootstrap collapse elements?

[image: Bootstrap collapse height issue]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="block-wrapper challenges-solutions">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="challenge-solution-header">
      <h3><i class="fab fas fa-file-contract"></i><span>Title 1</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge-solution-body">

      <button class="btn challenges-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expand-1">
        Challenge
      </button>

      <button class="btn solutions-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expand-2">
         Solution
       </button>

    </div>
    <div class="challenge-solution-footer">

      <div class="collapse" id="expand-1">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Expand 1 text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse" id="expand-2">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Expand 2 text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="challenge-solution-header">
      <h3><i class="fab fas fa-file-contract"></i><span>Title 2</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="challenge-solution-body">

      <button class="btn challenges-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expand-1">
        Challenge
      </button>

      <button class="btn solutions-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="expand-2">
         Solution
       </button>

    </div>
    <div class="challenge-solution-footer">

      <div class="collapse" id="expand-3">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Expand 1 text
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse" id="expand-4">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Expand 2 text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Here is a reproduction of the issue: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PauloNatal/o4vk2s79/37/)

I think the issue is with the row class. It will always expand side columns to match height. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Please read [mre] before posting to get the right answer for your questions

Comment: @Madeirense What you are probably looking for is _masonry layout_. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468140/bootstrap-4-masonry-layout-utilizing-flexbox-grid) question may help you.